# lost ubuntu partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, grubrescue

My Ubuntu crashed yesterday and after rebooting the grub rescue showed up. I've never used grub before but when I tried **ls** look like there are only Windows partitions there.

```
grub> ls
(memdisk) (loop0) (hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

I also tried booting from live CD and use fdisk. However there is no ubuntu partition listed. I am newbie and don't know what I can do next. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should stop using this harddrive alltogether. While booting into Windows should be *relatively* safe, you should better not have **any** writing access to this drive.

Next get your hands on a Live-CD, for example the disk that you used to install Ubuntu.
Boot into this livesystem, and fire up [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), to see, if it finds your missing partition:

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
sudo testdisk
```

The next steps are depending on your exact setup, and what is left of your partition.
You can find more information on the testdisk homepage, and possibly in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1376383)